# Print variable inside function 'wp_editor'

Tags: wordpress, twig

I am trying to define initial value for Wordpress textarea with twig.
So I use this code:

```
{% set job_text = "test text" %}
{{ fn('wp_editor', "{{ job_text }}", 'post_content', {'textarea_name':'post_content','media_buttons': 0, 'wpautop':true, 'editor_height':'200px', 'quicktags': 0} ) }}
```

But this code prints textarea with text `{{ job_text }}` instead of `test text`.
I used different options (like `job_text` or `{ job_text }`) but it still prints text, not a variable's value.

What I miss here?

Comment: The correct syntax is `{{ fn('wp_editor', job_text, '...` as `job_text` is a variable

Comment: OMG, I tried this option a lot of times but have been getting errors with rendering. But now it's FINE. Probably, there were other mistakes as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem. Thanks to @DarkBee.
It was incorrect syntax in `job_text` part.

Correct code is:

```
{% set job_text = "test text" %}
{{ fn('wp_editor', job_text, 'post_content', {'textarea_name':'post_content','media_buttons': 0, 'wpautop':true, 'editor_height':'200px', 'quicktags': 0} ) }}
```